# RuntimeException (Unexpected record type) when generating excel file with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using apache poi 3.9 for processing of excel file.Where I am generating excel file  based on some report.For others excel file its working fine but for report which has hyperlink in it ,java code is showing exception

```
Unexpected record type (org.apache.poi.hssf.record.HyperlinkRecord)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected record type (org.apache.poi.hssf.record.HyperlinkRecord)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.RowRecordsAggregate.<init>(RowRecordsAggregate.java:97)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.<init>(InternalSheet.java:172)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.createSheet(InternalSheet.java:127)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:291)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:243)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:187)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:322)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:303)
```

I have used apache poi `cell.getHyperlink` and `cell.getHyperlink.getAddress` methods.

Please tell me, how to resolve this exception.

Comment: "I have used apache poi `cell.getHyperlink` and `cell.getHyperlink.getAddress` methods." Can we see the code where you use those methods? Why do you use those methods?

Comment: Did you try with Apache POI 3.10, or even better a recent nightly build?

Comment: I have used getHyperlink and getHyperlink.getAddress methods for accessing the hyperlink associated with particular cell.

Comment: I have tried with apache poi 3.10 also but its not working